# Extract LINESTRING ZM geometry (XYZM) in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a linear layer of roads (every segment divided into many parts) with linestring geometry. I would like to generate a WKT linestring geometry in attribute table - coordinate X Y together (!) with Z and M values (XYZM for each nodes)

Example of a correct result: LINESTRING ZM ((540762.573877557 519541.938412964 0 0, 540715.013082288 519508.218571241 0 58))

The main problem is how to generate a X and Y and Z and M values for each nodes with a single query (!) in field calculator in QGIS or at export to csv.
I need this as one field in the attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new text field and fill it using the field calculator with this expression `geom_to_wkt($geometry)`, you should get what you want (I don't have ZM line to test it but on M line geometry I get a correct LineStingM output).

Comment: I tried many times this expression but as a result  I received Linestring XY without Z or M values (LineString (400769.83207874 388960.41467135, 400750.2455442 388945.12135447). In particular, I care about M values.

Comment: I tried this expression on the newly created layer. Now creates a field of geometry ZM (there is progress :)), but all M values ​​equals 0 (value 0 for Z is not a problem). result: LineStringZM (407457.8 388942.55 0 0, 407467.57198884 388883.22787227 0 0)

Comment: In my test only the first M value equal 0 (that's what's expected), the other one all have value. Are you sure that your M and Z value are not at 0 ? (to check just turn your layer in edit mode the use the vertex tool to right click on a line and select vertex editor, it will open a window with XYZM coordinate of all vertex)

Comment: There are also only 0 values. I probably do not have the M value set in the layer :(( How to set correctly M values in the layer?

Comment: I will add that I can generate nodes with M values from this line layer (processing --> Extract nodes). bBecause of that I was sure that I have set the values correctly

Comment: It's better to ask a new question on how to calibrate your line with M value. Alternatively you may look on this site for question about "linear referencing" or "dynamic segmentation" and you may also have a look at the LRS pluging : http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.1.1.1/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much J.R. for help!!! :)) I understand everything already. Lack of layer calibration was a problem.